# How did Kirk and Chekov survive the fall from the Enterprise bridge (ST Beyond)

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-beyond

**Star Trek Beyond spoilers!**

In *Star Trek Beyond*, Kirk and Chekov jump from the bridge of the Enterprise (JJ Abrams' NCC-1701) as it is tilting downwards. They slide down from the bridge, located in the middle of the saucer section, to the ground. At the point that they hit the ground, the saucer is perpendicular to the ground.

This is not directly comparable to jumping out of a building, as there is the friction from sliding, and it is not uniform acceleration since the saucer is constantly tilting. [This answer](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/a/8118) shows that about over 17m/s is likely to be fatal, which equates to about 12m of Earth free-fall. Surely even in the last section of falling where the saucer is near-vertical he (Kirk) travels 12m, or has accelerated to 17m/s.

Even if it is possible for him to *survive*, how can he roll with it and get up with no injuries, as Spock is the only one in the movie with plot-altering injuries?

Comment: Just one of many...
http://klaq.com/star-trek-beyond-more-plot-holes-than-the-galaxy-has-stars-spoilers/

Comment: Chekov wasn't in ST:B?

Comment: They were wearing [plot-armour](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/PlotArmor)

Comment: Are you taking into acount that the saucer generates its own gravity from within?

Comment: @DaveJohnson Chekov absolutely was in ST:B.  The actor who played Chekov died last year (2016), but he still appears throughout the film (clearly they had finished most or all of his scenes before his unfortunate demise.)

Comment: Because the writers wrote it like that.   Ultimately, who cares?   This is not the most physically impossible thing in the movie.